# Scroll to a specific section in the next page React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having Couple of li tags in homepage of React project like

```
<ul>
<li>abcd</li>
<li>efgh</li>
<li>ijkl</li>
<li>mnop</li>
<li>qrst</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting these data from my database but i am displaying only headings here. On clicking this heading i am redirected to another page say '/news'.

Now the problem i am facing is on clicking any li tag i must redirect to '/news' and then scroll to the particular section whose id i may pass as param in route or any other way of passing id like this.props.history.push() ( '/news' contains different sections for different news )

Comment: search for something `scrolling with react refs`

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz no issue i got that but how do i scroll at a particular id i mean first i have to set id to react.createRef or something like that

Comment: assign each item with and id say the div its wrapped in has id="abc" , then scroll to that div when component gets mounted. Get the id in the lifecycle hook and then scroll.

Comment: Read this https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-scroll-to-item

Comment: or an npm package would help https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz yea thnks dude

Comment: You can use scroll into view using refs.

Comment: @amardeepsaini ya but how do i store a id in my ref ? any reference ?

Comment: No need to store what you can do is name you ref same as your heading with space trimmed with underscore.